# TypeORM, TypeScript, and Jest Environment

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm

I would like to use TypeORM, TypeScript, and a Jest Environment, so I can use a docblock comment to DRY my tests up.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string

```
/**
 * @jest-environment ./test/db_environment.ts
 */

describe("my new test", () => { // ...
```

I currently have working specs that look like:

```
import { dbAfterAll, dbBeforeAll } from "@/test/db"

describe("my old test", () => {
  beforeAll(dbBeforeAll)
  afterAll(dbAfterAll)
  // ...
```

I created a file `./test/db_environment.ts` that inlines code from `@/test/db`:

```
import NodeEnvironment from "jest-environment-node"
import { AppDataSource } from "@/config/database"

class DbEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  dbConnection: typeof AppDataSource

  async setup() {
    await super.setup()
    this.dbConnection = await AppDataSource.initialize()
    await this.dbConnection.synchronize(true)
  }

  async teardown() {
    if (this.dbConnection) await this.dbConnection.destroy()
    await super.teardown()
  }
}

export default DbEnvironment
```

When I try to run a trivial test:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment ./test/db_environment.ts
 */

describe("jest-environment", () => {
  it("works", () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

I get errors due to TypeScript and Babel.

```
/app/models/datum.ts:1
    import {
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I found a suggestion to update my `jest.config.ts` to include options for `ts-jest`, like:

```
const config: Config = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        isolatedModules: true,
      },
    ],
  // ...
```

That changed the error to:

```
/app/models/index.ts:1
    export { Key } from "./key"
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I'm not sure what other context is needed, so here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register", "dotenv/config"]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

`jest.config.ts`:

```
// Jest configuration
import type { Config } from "jest"

const config: Config = {
  verbose: true,
  maxWorkers: 1,
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
  },
  collectCoverage: process.env.COVERAGE === "true",
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 95,
      functions: 100,
      lines: 70,
      statements: -2,
    },
  },
  testRegex: ".spec.ts$",
  coverageReporters: ["lcov", "text"],
  coverageDirectory: "./output/code-coverage/",
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "^<rootDir>/db/",
    "^<rootDir>/test/",
    "^<rootDir>/config/",
  ],
}

export default config
```

`babel.config.js`:

```
// Only for Jest
module.exports = { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] }
```

`test/db.ts`:

```
import { AppDataSource } from "@/config/database"

let connection: typeof AppDataSource

export async function dbBeforeAll(): Promise<void> {
  connection = await AppDataSource.initialize()
  await connection.synchronize(true)
}

export async function dbAfterAll(): Promise<void> {
  await connection.destroy()
}
```